# Creating a 3x3 Matrix and ordering numbers in a vortex from smaller to bigger

Tags: c#, matrix

i would like to create a 3x3 matrix with input numbers and then orders number from smaller to bigger and place it in the matrix like a vortex like : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and place number 1 to 0.0 position,2 to 0.1, 3 to 0.2, 4 to 1.2, 5 to 2.2, 6 to 2.1, 7 to 2.0, 8 to 1.0 and 9 to 1.1.

```
const int MATRIX_ROWS = 3;
        const int MATRIX_COLUMNS = 3;
        List<int> l = new List<int>(l);

        double[,] matrix = new double[MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLUMNS];
        for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS * MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++i)
        {
            int input;
            Console.Write("Enter value");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter correct value!");
            }
            l.Add(input);
        }
        l.Sort();
        for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = l[i * 3 + j];
            }
```

I start like that to get input numbers and i would like help for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will present you with the "vortex like" result for the matrix:

```
            List<int> nums = new List<int>();
            double[,] matrix = new double[3,3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            {
                double input;
                Console.Write("Enter value");
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter correct value!");
                }
                nums.Add(int.Parse(input.ToString()));
            }
            nums.Sort();
            int block = 0;
            int[] order = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
            for (int i = 0 ; i < order.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (block)
                {
                    case 0:
                        matrix[block, order[i]] = nums[i];
                        if (i == 2)
                            block = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (i < order.Length - 3)
                        {
                            matrix[block, order[i]] = nums[i];
                            block = 2;
                        }
                        else
                            matrix[block, order[i]] = nums[i];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(i == order.Length - 3)
                        {
                            matrix[block, order[i]] = nums[i];
                            block = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            matrix[block, order[i]] = nums[i];
                        break;

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The Resulting Matrix is:");

            for (int row = 0, col = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("row " + row + ": {0} - {1} - {2}", matrix[row, col], matrix[row, col + 1], matrix[row, col + 2]);
                col = 0;
            }
```

EDIT:now it displays the results.

Comment: I tried that too but that make me only insert 9 numbers and then does nothing else. Any thought?

Comment: the matrix variable will be populated in the "vortex" way,if you place a breakpoint just after the for loop you will see that it is correctly populated.

Comment: you probably want to display the result thats what you mean by "then does nothing else".i will edit to present the results on screen.

Comment: @terrybozzio That's exactly what i meant. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

As I see it - you can declare a `List<int> l` somewhere at the beginning, read the whole data by `l.Add(x);` then perform `l.Sort()` and after the data is sorted - populate your matrix. Let me know if you have further questions.

So you will get something like

```
const int MATRIX_ROWS = 3;
const int MATRIX_COLUMNS = 3;
List<int> l = new List<int>();

double[,] matrix = new double[MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLUMNS];
for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS * MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++i)
{
        double input;
        Console.Write("Enter value");
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter correct value!");
        }
        l.Add(input);
}
l.Sort();
for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = l[i*3 + j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste my code and show me how you would use that, because im not much used with c# and im still learning. Thank you

Comment: I did edit up how i had to modify it but i still get 1 error there:       List<int> l = new List<int>(l);  use of unassigned local variable (l), how i can solve that?

Comment: Change that kine to `List<int> l = new List<int>();`

Comment: Accepting my answer would be appreciated )

Comment: Ah, you chose the other one - no problem.